# ElasticSearch: -ve boosting documents at index time

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I would like to know if its possible to down weight some of the documents at index time, based on list of terms?

Lets say I have a document containing following fileds:
- name,
- description,
- title

I want to down weight anything which has "xyz" in the filed "name". So when I search for xyz, all docs having "xyz" in the "name" filed will have less score than other docs with "news" in "description" field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [boosting query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/boosting-query.html) to "downgrade" results which match a particular query clause:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_all/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "boosting" : {
         "negative_boost" : 1,
         "negative" : {
            "match" : {
               "name" : "xyz"
            }
         },
         "positive" : {
            "match" : {
               "description" : "news"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you provide an example of how can I do this with java apis. All I'm trying to do is fetching the records from DB and indexing them with the negative weight if "name" field contains "xyz".

Comment: My current code looks like: [java-code-for-es-indexing](http://pastebin.com/aW1AvFRW)

Comment: This really helped. I was able to achieve this using following:

      builder = QueryBuilders.boostingQuery().negative(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("sTitle", "Traffic Weather News").operator(Operator.OR))
            .negativeBoost(-100).positive(builder);